# Outlook notifications not popping up

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Right after my Outlook upgraded to 2016 on Windows 8, I am no longer getting the New Email Alerts like I used to, while new emails successfully arrive in my Inbox folder.

Outlook itself is still configured to “Display a Desktop Alert” but it doesn’t show any more now.

Can I somehow get the old big alert and sound back when a new message arrives?

There is a fix for [Windows 10](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/no-new-mail-alert-on-windows-10), in which it says, "*for some strange reason, Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016 don’t always get all their notification methods enabled on Windows*". But I didn't find a fix for Windows 8.

Comment: Have you tried repairing and/or reinstalling Outlook yet?

Comment: To reinstall Outlook just for this misconfiguration is surely an overkill. Given that my Outlook is freshly installed, I highly doubt that reinstallation can do anything. Repairing? Yes, but how?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b

Comment: Some extra things to look at here including some cross application issues: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/855

Comment: @Sun, I can accept that as the answer as my Outlook is "*not listed as a Notification app*", as covered in the article.

Comment: @xpt I've made into an answer. Windows 8, the new Millenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure Outlook 2013's App Notification is enabled in Windows 8 settings. It is normal that Outlook 2013 is not enabled by default, but if Outlook 2013 is installed, it should show up on your App Notification list to enable.

[Delayed or no New Mail Notifications for Outlook 2013 on Windows 8](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/855)